# Django Python runserver not working after closing. ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

So I was just trying some random Django practicing, and after finishing I closed the server and command prompt and everything. Now when I go to open in again. when I run python manage.py runserver I get this error[image]

I don't know what to because everything worked fine before I closed the app, now nothing's opening.

Comment: can you share the project file system?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have it on Github because I was just kind of playing around with it, so you'll have to look through this zip and view the files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0GZaFVDqihkTXJ_dHGYvu3TKBbSuei0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/w5sEL

Comment: you are missing the inner **djangoproject/** directory under your project directory **djangoproject**, which contains `__init__.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py`, `wsgi.py`. refer to [offical doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)

Comment: Oh, yeah the folder was accidentally deleted at a point. I recoverd it and now everything works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, glad it works for you, cheers :)